# How to prevent malware to know when removable devices are plugged in

Tags: malware

The question is clear, I'm a programmer and wrote a software to disinfect the USB devices when they got the malware which hides the files and creates a shortcut of the virus .
Using this soft we can disinfect the data, But if the USB is replugged it'll get infected again ...

at this point I'm trying to prevent malwares from knowing when removable devices are plugged in, any ideas?

Comment: Uninstall the USB driver?

Answer (score 4):

Computers are not good at detecting evil. Meaning that you cannot make an automated test which can tell you if some software, which detects USB device plugging, is "malware" or "not malware".

As long as a machine:

- currently runs malware (i.e. is subverted);
- and can detect *at all* that a USB device is plugged;

then the malware can see the USB device and do everything that it wishes to do on it.

To prevent malware on a given machine from noticing that a USB device is plugged, then, you only have two possibilities:

1. Remove the malware from the machine.
2. Don't plug the USB device.

From your description, what you are trying to do is analogous to the following: when a hospital is on fire, how do we arrange for the flames not to notice when a new patient enters, so that the flames don't actually incinerate him ? This ridiculous metaphor is meant to illustrate the idea that you might be trying to solve the problem by the wrong end, with predictably suboptimal results.

Comment: To prevent malware on a given machine from noticing that a USB device is plugged, then, you only have two possibilities:

    Remove the malware from the machine.
    Don't plug the USB device.
why only this options ? in programming there is an event that notice you when a device is plugged in. when a hospital is on fire we can cover new patient's eye ,can't we ? ;)

Comment: @Black-Hole - Unfortunately, that requires that whatever you're covering the patient with not already be on fire.  If a computer system is subverted, it's best to consider _anything_ and **everything** suspect - that is, you can't restrict access to the notifications (reliably, if at all even _normally_).  Essentially, your nursing staff is going to a closet for fire blankets, but isn't checking to see if they're on fire (or even just heated to human flash-point temperature) first.